# Selecting text including $ in Sublime Text 3

Tags: selection, sublimetext, sublimetext3, double-click

I'm a former Netbeans user, who finally came out of the darkness toward light and started using Sublime Text 3.

I personally adore this editor, but there is one, quite tiny, yet annoying, thing. When double clicking any piece of text, ST3 selects entire word. If this is variable name (that is -- `$` stands in the beginning), it does nothing special, it still selects word only. Netbeans (and probably many other IDEs) does select word + `$` in this case.

Is there any way (macro, snippet, key binding), that I could achieve the same in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: +1 bcause its a useful question for those using languages ​​like php, which use *$* prefixed variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When double clicking any piece of text, Sublime Text selects words. The *$* character its considered to be a word separator.

Fortunately, you can change this behavior by modifying the *word_separators* stting in the Sublime preferences. So, **remove the *$* character from the *word_separators* setting** and save the new setting to your user settings (*Preferences > 'Settings - User'*).
This is the original setting (located in *Preferences > 'Settings - Default'*) with the *$* character already removed:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Comment: A perfect answer! Introduction, step-by-step solution and ready-to-use example. What to expect more? :]